# How to send dynamic headers in the request using Axios.interceptor in react

Tags: axios, interceptor

Since we are sending the apikey in all the request, we had configured that in axios.interceptor to attach the apikey for all the requests.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (requestConfig) => {
    requestConfig.headers = {
      ...{
        apikey: getApikey()
      }
    }
    return requestConfig
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
)
```

Now I am working on an API where I need to add few other fields in the header alongwith the apikey. When I try to add it in the request, it gets overwritten by axios.interceptor.

Can anyone tell me how to send dynamic header with axios.interceptor. I read that we can create an instance using axios.create.Is that the only way or some other ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You should spread the original request headers so that they're not overwritten, like so:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (requestConfig) => {
    requestConfig.headers = {
      // Spread the original headers
      ...requestConfig.headers,
      // Add the API key
      apikey: getApikey()
    }
    return requestConfig
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
)
```